# Export to Excel in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, export-to-excel

I am trying to export the db values as excel using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

This is my code

```
public IActionResult GetExcel()
{
    var excel = (from i in _context.EmployeeBasicInformations 
                 where i.FormCurrentStatus == "CanditateCreated" && 
                       i.IsActive == 1 select i).ToList();

    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Students");
        worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Employee Id";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Employee First Name";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 3).Value = "Employee Last Name";
        worksheet.Cell(1, 4).Value = "Aadhar";

        IXLRange range = worksheet.Range(worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Address, worksheet.Cell(1, 4).Address);
        range.Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Almond);

        int index = 1;

        foreach (var item in excel)
        {
            index++;

            worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = item.EmployeeId;
            worksheet.Cell(index, 2).Value = item.EmployeeFirstName;
            worksheet.Cell(index, 3).Value = item.EmployeeLastName;
            worksheet.Cell(index, 4).Value = item.EmployeeAadharCardNumber;
         }

         using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
             workbook.SaveAs(stream);
             var content = stream.ToArray();
             string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

             var strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
             string filename = string.Format($"Students_{strDate}.xlsx");

             return File(content, contentType, filename);
         }
     }
}
```

While inspecting, I am able to see the file getting generated, but I am getting these errors:

> 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> 'stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

I am not sure what is happening - please help.

Comment: Everything works fine on new asp.net core 7 solution